# how to check the app is installed for first time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

is there a way to check the app is installed for first time.I want this info cause i want to provide a small introduction session about the app features when user run the app for the first time.I want this to develop in windows phone 8.1 in c#
any help is welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somethink like this:

On ApplicationStart:

**Windows Phone 8:**

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("FirstStart"))
{
    //ShowTutorial
}else
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (!settings.Contains("FirstStart"))
    {
        settings.Add("FirstStart", "false");
    }
    //Start normal.
}
```

Here is a quickstart about Application Settings on Windows Phone: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

**Windows Phone 8.1**

On ApplicationStart:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (localSettings.Values["FirstStart"] == null)
{
    //ShowTutorial
}
else
{
    localSettings.Values["FirstStart"] = "true";
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.ASPx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: thanx for reply  but i want this thing windows phone 8.1

Comment: where should i place this code in app.xaml.cs on launch or somewhere else

Comment: As before in your application start.

Comment: Using Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Roaming instead of .Current could save the data in the cloud and even on re-install you would know that it has been used before. This would also be handy if you want to know this in Windows Apps and not just on the phone as this is a shared storage if you have a universal app.